# SparkR context in Java

Tags: java, r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have a spring application and I have defined spark as a **maven dependency**.
As specified in the [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#linking-with-spark).

Now I am able to generate the **Spark Context** by initializing the constructor **JavaSparkContext** in my class file :-

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master);
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

I have read the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#starting-up-sparkcontext-sqlcontext) of **SparkR** it says one needs a spark context created by sparkR as :

```
sc <- sparkR.init()
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
```

This is from the SparkR console present in the spark binaries.

I need to do the same thing from within java so I see a package with **R** api in the core spark package which I added as dependency in maven during setup above.

```
package org.apache.spark.api.r;
```

My questions :

1. Does the above package contain complete set of **SparkR** [apis](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/) ?
2. How do I invoke these SparkR apis, i.e. I have to instantiate some object and then say I have an array of numbers and I want to invoke **avg** function of SparkR in the apis link above, how do I do it in Java?

Comment: It looks like you have a wrong impression what SparkR is actually doing. It is not R implementation on JVM or Java interface to R.

Comment: @zero323 I just want to invoke SparkR api in Java. The website has code samples of scala and python. Invoking from Java is possible as per documentation, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: But what is the point? Supported SparkR API is just a subset of Spark SQL API.  And `org.apache.spark.api.r` is just a set of wrappers.

Comment: @zero323 Ok I got it wrong than.In java I want to invoke the functions mentioned in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html

I have SparkContext and SqlContext , is there anyway of invoking the functions above from Java? If yes please wrtie it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: No there isn't. These are only thin wrappers around Java / Scala API which can be used directly: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$